# How to add a parameter to 'request' when redirecting a page?

Tags: magento2, redirect-url, response

**My code in Rooter.php:**

```
$this->_response->setRedirect('customer/account/create');
$request->setDispatched(true);
$request->setParam('nickname', $request->getPathInfo());
return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect::class);
```

**My code in register.phtml:**

```
$sponsor = $block->getRequest()->getParam('nickname');
```

**$sponsor** returns null because **params: array(0)**

Answer (score 0):

You have already *done the something at your code*

> setParam('nickname', $request->getPathInfo())

Using `setParam()` you can **pass a parameter to the controller**.

Suppose,
You have added another parameter like

```
setParam('myname', 'Nuno Sousa')
```

At Controller's Action file' you  get this `myname` field value
by using below code:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('myname')
```

At  block you can  get value by `$this->getRequest()->getParam('myname')`
and  phtml `$block->getRequest()->getParam('myname')`

Comment: My issue was in phtml Amit. I used $sponsor = $block->getRequest()->getParam('nickname'); in my register.phtml file and $sponsor return null. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: In register.phtml I get params: array(0)